What should I do with the unbound variable?
(define (subtractMatHelper list1 acc)
    (if(null?list1)
        acc
        (   (define newList (cons(-(car(car list1)) (car(car(cdr list1)))) acc)) ;the subtraction of the first element inthe current matrix
            (subtractMatHelper (list (cdr(car list1)) (cdr(car list1))) newList) ;the recursive call 
         )
    )
)


(define (subtractMat iniTlist)
    (subtractMatHelper iniTlist '())
)

I need to produce a list of the subtraction of a two row matrix using a tailrecursion in scheme but i am having an unbound variable. Scheme is new to me a nd i dont know whaat to do or what is happening in my code right now.

You can't just throw in random  parentheses. More conventional formatting and variable names would help make your code more readable, too...

@Shawn That's all true, but not very helpful without explaining the correct option, nor very friendly.

Spaces are important. (null?list1) should be (null? list1)

( (define ...) (subtractMatHelper ...)) should be (begin (define ...) (subtractMatHelper)). You can't just wrap statements and expressions in a list, you have to use the begin statement to group them.

The parentheses are not used for "block structuring" the way curly brackets are in many other languages.
